# ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint, I've checked for syntax and spelling errors

Tags: mysql, sql

I am getting a ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint error with:
Foreign Key (locationID) references Location (locationID). When I comment it out the query goes through with no problem

I can't seem to find the problem I have checked for spelling errors, notepad++ highlights "Location" and "locationID" on both statements. They are also both `varchar(3)`.

```
create table Location 
(
    warehouseID varchar(3),
    locationID varchar(3),
    Aisle int,
    Shelf int,
    Bin int,
    capacity Double,
    Primary Key (warehouseID,locationID),
    Foreign Key (warehouseID) references Warehouse(warehouseID)
) Engine = InnoDB;

create table Prod_Location 
(
    warehouseID varchar(3),
    locationID varchar(3),
    productNum int,
    quantityOnHand int,
    Foreign Key (warehouseID) references Warehouse(warehouseID),
    Foreign Key (productNum) references Product(productNum),
    Foreign Key (locationID) references Location(locationID),
    Primary Key (warehouseID, locationID, productNum)
) Engine = InnoDB;
```

Thank you.

Edit:
Full code

```
create database WareMart30119267;
use WareMart30119267;

create table Department (
    dptNumber int Auto_Increment,
    dptName varchar(20),
    Primary Key (dptNumber))
    Engine = InnoDB;

create table Product (
    productNum int Auto_Increment,
    description varchar(30),
    packSize int,
    Price Decimal(10,2),
    dptNumber int,
    Primary Key (productNum),
    Foreign Key (dptNumber) references Department(dptNumber))
    Engine = InnoDB;

create table CLient (
    clientNum int Auto_Increment,
    clientName varchar(40),
    Primary Key (clientNum))
    Engine = InnoDB;


create table Client_Address (
    clientNum int Auto_Increment,
    addressType varchar(1),
    street varchar(20),
    city varchar(3),
    state varchar(3),
    postcode varchar(4),
    Primary Key (clientNum, addressType),
    Foreign Key (clientNum) references Client(clientNum))
    Engine = InnoDB;

create table Stock_Request (
    requestNum int Auto_Increment,
    requestDate date,
    clientNum int,
    Primary Key (requestNum),
    Foreign Key (clientNum) references Client(clientNum))
    Engine = InnoDB;

create table Request_List (
    requestNum int,
    productNum int,
    qtyRequested int,
    Primary Key (requestNum, productNum),
    Foreign Key (requestNum) references Stock_Request(requestNum),
    Foreign Key (productNum) references Product(productNum))
    Engine = InnoDB;

create table Warehouse (
    warehouseID varchar(3),
    street varchar(20),
    city varchar(15),
    state varchar(3),
    postcode varchar(4),
    managerID int,
    Primary Key (warehouseID))
    Engine = InnoDB;

create table Location (
    warehouseID varchar(3),
    locationID varchar(3),
    Aisle int,
    Shelf int,
    Bin int,
    capacity Double,
    Primary Key (warehouseID, locationID),
    Foreign Key (warehouseID) references Warehouse(warehouseID))
    Engine = InnoDB;

create table Employee (
    staffID int Auto_Increment,
    surname varchar(20),
    firstName varchar(15),
    dob date,
    street varchar(20),
    city varchar(15),
    state varchar(3),
    postcode varchar(4),
    salary Decimal(19,4),
    warehouseID varchar(3),
    supervisedBy int,
    Primary Key (staffID),
    Foreign Key (supervisedBy) references Employee(staffID))
    Engine = InnoDB;
/*Add Foreign Keys to Warehouse and Employee */

alter table Warehouse
    add Foreign Key (managerID) references Employee(staffID);

alter table Employee
    add Foreign Key (warehouseID) references Warehouse(warehouseID); 


create table Prod_Location (
    warehouseID varchar(3),
    locationID varchar(3),
    productNum int,
    quantityOnHand int,
    Foreign Key (warehouseID) references Warehouse(warehouseID),
    Foreign Key (productNum) references Product(productNum),
    Foreign Key (locationID) references Location(locationID),
    Primary Key (warehouseID,locationID,productNum))
    Engine = InnoDB;

create table Picking_List (
    warehouseID varchar(3),
    locationID varchar(3),
    productNum int,
    requestNum int,
    quantityPicked int,
    datePicked date,
    pickerStaffID int,
    Primary Key (warehouseID, locationID, productNum, requestNum),
    /* Foreign Key (warehouseID) references Warehouse(warehouseID), */
    Foreign Key (locationID, warehouseID) references Location(locationID, warehouseID),
    Foreign Key (productNum) references Product(productNum),
    Foreign Key (requestNum) references Stock_Request(requestNum))
    Engine = InnoDB;
```

I feel stupid now, the answer was to move warehouseID and locationID in the primary key so it was like this

```
create table Location (
warehouseID varchar(3),
locationID varchar(3),
Aisle int,
Shelf int,
Bin int,
capacity Double,
Primary Key (locationID, warehouseID),
Foreign Key (warehouseID) references Warehouse(warehouseID))
Engine = InnoDB;
```

I don't know why the order made a difference but it fixed the error.

Comment: You have a spelling error in the title, right where you say you've checked for spelling errors.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Your primary key on `location` is defined as the composite key:

```
Primary Key (warehouseID,locationID),
```

Whereas you are trying to reference this in Prod_Location as a foreign key via just one of its components:

```
Foreign Key (locationID) references Location(locationID)
```

You'll need to change the foreign key to be composite with all fields of the referenced key:

```
Foreign Key (warehouseID, locationID) references Location(warehouseID, locationID)
```

Or, alternatively, change the primary key of Location to be simple, e.g. just `locationID`

**Edit** After the full schema posted
My apologies - the order of the composite keys is important - you'll need to keep the same order of the primary key definition in the foreign key references, viz `(warehouseID, locationID)`.

This also needs to be done for the composite foreign key to `Location` in `Picking_List`.

Also, since `clientNum` is a foreign key in table `Client_Address` back to client, it itself should not be declared as `Auto_Increment`, since it must stay in synch with `Client` and be explicitly assigned in code.

One of the common problems with composite foreign keys is the temptation to reference and join to the ultimate component key tables directly, instead of to the link table via the composite keys. I believe that the direct relationship between `Prod_Location` and `warehouseId` via `Foreign Key (warehouseID) references Warehouse(warehouseID)` may be an example of this.

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4afe17)

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've added your foreign key and it still gives me the same error so I tried to comment out Foreign Key (warehouseID) references Warehouse(warehouseID), with no luck either

Comment: I can't change the Primary key it has to be a composite one, we were given a ER diagram and database schema we have to follow.

Comment: I goofed and swapped the order of the keys in the original post. My apologies.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, sadly we can't change the structure of the database. We have to use the one that was given to use by the lecturer.
I told the lecture about clientNum and he said it shouldn't be a auto increment he made a mistake in the assignment thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Remove Primary key from Pro_Location Table:

```
create table Location (
    warehouseID varchar(3),
    locationID varchar(3),
    Aisle int,
    Shelf int,
    Bin int,
    capacity Double,
    Primary Key (warehouseID,locationID),
    Foreign Key (warehouseID) references Warehouse(warehouseID))
    Engine = InnoDB;

create table Prod_Location (
    warehouseID varchar(3),
    locationID varchar(3),
    productNum int,
    quantityOnHand int,
    Foreign Key (warehouseID) references Warehouse (warehouseID),
    Foreign Key (productNum) references Product (productNum),
    Foreign Key (locationID) references Location (locationID)
    Engine = InnoDB;
```

Comment: please specify your all three table structure.

Comment: why do you use varchar(3) when it is ID (warehouseID,locationID) ?

Comment: That's what we have to use, I can't change any of the data types
I've put up the full sql.

Answer (score 0):

I feel stupid now, the answer was to move warehouseID and locationID in the primary key so it was like this

```
create table Location (
warehouseID varchar(3),
locationID varchar(3),
Aisle int,
Shelf int,
Bin int,
capacity Double,
Primary Key (locationID, warehouseID),
Foreign Key (warehouseID) references Warehouse(warehouseID))
Engine = InnoDB;
```

I don't know why the order made a difference but it fixed the error.